# MySQL query with a sub-query disconnects before finished

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Given four tables in two databases, a and b

- a.civicrm_contact
- a.civicrm_group_contact
- a.civicrm_group b.node
- b.node

In in the code , database b is daweb2012_drupal

```
select
    a.id,
    a.sort_name,
    b.status,
    c.title
    -- other requested columns here
from
    civicrm_contact a, civicrm_group_contact b, civicrm_group c
where
    a.id = b.contact_id
and
    b.group_id = c.id
and
    b.status = 'Added'
and
    a.id in
(select
    a.id
from
    civicrm_contact a, 
    civicrm_group_contact b, 
    daweb2012_drupal.da_core_country_map d
where
    a.id = b.contact_id
and
    b.status in ('Added', 'Pending')
and
    b.contact_id != 1
and
    b.group_id = d.id
and
    d.group_type = 'dacountry_group'
group by
    b.contact_id
having
    count(b.contact_id) > 1
   )
```

The goal here is to display the detail for contacts who are in more than one civicrm_group and that group is a 'da_country' group.

When I run this query from MySQL Workbench, it disconnects before it completes.
When I run it from a cli, it never completes.

I have run the subquery standalone and it returns the correct results but I cannot understand why when used as a sub-query, it never completes.

Comment: This query has now been running 4 hours with no results

Comment: I have changed the original question with the current code I am running, which still does not work.